# HTML user input is not recognized when form is posted on PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to figure out why the person's name, taken via a html form, does not show on the corresponding php page when it is called. The input from the rest of the form works perfectly, input from the html page is recognized and shown on the corresponding php page.

The HTML:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="LayoutDiv1">Welcome</div>
  <form action="website.php" method="POST">
  <div id="LayoutDiv3">         Names:
           <input type="text" name="user"/>   //User variable here
           Gender<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT>
    <select name="Gender[]" double="double">
             <option value="Female">Female</option>
             <option value="Male">Male</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

The PHP:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="LayoutDiv1"> Hi <?php ($_POST ["user"]) ?>  //Nothing appears
</div>
```

The CSS for the PHP page:

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background:#FFF
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<?php echo ($_POST ["user"]) ?>
```

echo function will print the user variable.